# Is a warrant with the same strike price and maturity as the corresponding call option priced in the same way as the call option?

Tags: options, warrant

Is a warrant with the same strike price and maturity as the corresponding call option priced in the same way as the call option? Suppose I find a strike X warrant with T years to expiry and a call option on the same stock with the same strike X and T years to expiry. If they both entitle me to buy 1 share will they be priced in the same way? What contract specifications and complications regarding the warrant could cause the prices to deviate?

Comment: The slight complication is that if the warrant will be exercised, new shares will be issued by the company, if a call is exercised you just get existing shares that someone already has (or buys in the marketplace) and delivers to you.

Comment: So when warrants are exercised there is dilution to the current shareholders?

Comment: So would it make sense to divide the BS call price by 1+the ratio of warrants to stock to obtain the BS warrant price?

Comment: Only before the warrant is issued. After it has been issued it is accounted as a liability so there is no stock price dilution on the exercise date, and the warrant and the call should be priced the same way.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't the time of exercise of the warrants play a part though? Suppose they were all exercised simultaneously vs slowly over a 5 year period.

Comment: Warrants are also issued by someone. If you had two warrants, with identical parameters (ie strike underlying maturity etc.) one issued by Germany, and one issued by Greece, then the German issued warrant is worth more, since there is less chance of Germany defaulting.

Comment: Im considering stock warrants but I suppose the default consideration applies to companies as well.